# Reading JSON and XML from Rails on C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json

I need to read some lists returned in JSON and XML from a WebService. We're using C# with .NET Framework 4.

Here is a example of JSON:

> [{"category":{"category_name":"Imagens","category_desc":null,"parent_id":0,"created_at":"2012-03-18T00:07:20Z","updated_at":"2012-03-18T00:07:20Z","id":1}},
>
> {"category":"category_name":"V\u00eddeos","category_desc":null,"parent_id":0,"created_at":"2012-03-18T00:07:20Z","updated_at":"2012-03-18T00:07:20Z","id":2}}]

And here, XML:

```
<categories>
  <category>
    <category-name>Imagens</category-name>
    <category-desc></category-desc>
    <parent-id>0</parent-id>
    <created-at>2012-03-18T00:07:20Z</created-at>
    <updated-at>2012-03-18T00:07:20Z</updated-at>
    <id>1</id>
  </category>
  <category>
    <category-name>Videos</category-name>
    <category-desc></category-desc>
    <parent-id>0</parent-id>
    <created-at>2012-03-18T00:07:20Z</created-at>
    <updated-at>2012-03-18T00:07:20Z</updated-at>
    <id>2</id>
  </category>
</categories>
```

Remember that this replies are comming from a Ruby on Rails application, so i can't change its format.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: So what is the problem you face? Have you tried something yet? (Note: You can edit your question to add updates.)

Comment: The easiest way to do it is create a class Model that matches the properties and use with an Xml desearilizer or a DataContract and desearlize the json.

Comment: I overlooked the obvious too, you could use System.Xml and parse the Xml document and do what ever you want to do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic jObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
foreach (var cat in jObj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cat.category.category_name);
}
```

BTW: Your server app doesn't form a valid json object. there is a missing `{` between `"category"` and `"category_name"` in the second line.

Comment: Hi folks, thanks. I'm comming from C/C++ so i'm learning about this Desearializer and LINQ features that C# have!